# Current status of cubical inductive families

Tags: type-theory, cubical-type-theory, provers, cubical-agda, inductive-family

I have the impression that cubical type theory hasn't dealt with inductive families yet. But the only source on this matter I can get is [this Agda issue](https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/3733). What I've gathered is

- Agda supports defining (higher) inductive families, but `transp` doesn't compute on them.
- The nighly version of Agda currently displays a warning about not being able to generate equivalences. But Agda 2.6.2.2 doesn't even display this warning.
- The other cubical proof assistants I inverstigated don't seem to support inductive families.

What's the status on this matter? In particular,

- Is there a conjectured (complete or partial) set of rules in this situation?
- If so, is there any theoretical analysis (consistency, canonicity, normalization) of these rules?
- To what extent have the rules been implemented in any cubical proof assistant?

Comment: In https://univalent-math.github.io/ (ICMS 2020) there is a talk by Vezzosi about a construction (`transpX`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would take a look at [Higher inductive types in cubical computational type theory](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3290314) by Evan Cavallo and Bob Harper.

This paper provides:

- A complete set of rules for the formation and computation of higher inductive families
- A canonicity result

Fair warning that the rules are pretty brutal and difficult to read, and I make no claim to understand them myself.

It uses Cartesian cubical type theory, instead of the DeMorgan cubical type theory implemented in Agda, so there is no mention of `transp`. The closest thing is `coe`, which allows coercion between arbitrary dimension variables along a line of types.

To my knowledge, this paper has never been implemented in its entirety in a cubical proof assistant. [redtt](https://github.com/RedPRL/redtt) implements the non-indexed fragment.